# How serialversionID is working in deserialization in java

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class like

```
class Stundent
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     private int no;
     private String name;

    //setters and getters
}
```

And then i used the following code for serialization & deserialization

```
public class Serialization{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("out.ser");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        SerializeMe serializeMe = new SerializeMe(1);
        oos.writeObject(serializeMe);
        oos.close();    
    }
}


 public class DeSerialization{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

       File file = new File("out.ser");
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
     ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    SerializeMe dto = (SerializeMe) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println("data : " + dto.getData());
    ois.close();   
    }
}
```

After running the Serialization class i changed the serialiversionID to 2 and then i run the second program,then i got like

```
 java.io.InvalidClassException:
SerializeMe; local class incompatible
```

That means whenever i am performing deserialization 
serialversionID of Student class is checking.

**My doubt is**

1)Is it mandatory to have Student class at the time of deserialization ?

2)As per serialization definition, to transfer the java objects as stream of bytes through network we are performing serialization.So if an object is transferred through network ,how the Student class is available in other side.

> For example in my application every entity(Hibernate entity) is
>   Serializable.
>       Because my web application exist in different server and my database
>       is in differentserver.That is the reason we have implemented 
>       Serializable.In this case can u explain how serialization is working?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deserialize a serialized object, the same class has to be present in order to construct an instance of that class.

The `serialVersionUID` is to tell whether the same version of the class is present in terms of the serialization process. If the class that is present has a different `serialVersionUID` value (compared to the value read from the binary data/stream of the serialized object), deserialization will be aborted by throwing an `InvalidClassException`.

> 1)Is it mandatory to have Student class at the time of deserialization?

Yes.

> 2)As per serialization definition, to transfer the java objects as stream of bytes through network we are performing serialization.So if an object is transferred through network ,how the Student class is available in other side.

You have to take care of that. You have to distribute the `Student` class prior to deserializing a serialized `Student`.

Deserialization can only happen if the same version (determined by the `serialVersionUID` value) exists of the serialized class. Serializing instances of the standard lib is not a problem, because those are present in all JRE's (although different versions might be present with different `serialVersionUID` fields!), so you can "transfer" such objects between different JRE's. If an instance of a custom class is transferred, the same class file must be made available at the destination prior to the deserialization process.

**Edit:**

You wrote that your "web application exists on different servers". Your web application includes your class files which implicitly means that the class files will be available on all servers. So a serialized object from one server can be deserialized on another.

Comment: Can u check my second question?

Comment: For example in my application every entity(Hibernate entity) is Serializable.Because my web application exist in different server and my database is in different server.That is the reason we have implemented Serializable.In this case can u explain how serialization is working?

Comment: did you understand my question ?

Comment: Here entities means my custom classes only(In hibernate for every database table we will create one equivalent  java class)

Comment: I mean my web application is available in one server,i am connecting to other server which has database through JNDI.At that time my code is not available in the second server which contains database.

Comment: Ya i understood from you point.To transfer the data (object with values not the class) here we are performing serialization am i right ?

Comment: Yes. Transfer means serialize, send the bytes, and deserialize on the other side.

Comment: But my example question is not solved.Because my class is not available in the second server.

Comment: Believe me, if the class is not present on the other side, you will not get any deserialized instance from that class.

Comment: Whatever you are saying i understood.Exactly you are correct.But i am unable to understand what is happening in my scenario.Any how thanks for good help.+1

Answer (score -1):

As far as my understanding is concerned, usually when we transfer objects, it is the attribute values inside the Student object is what we are require.

The Student class should be present on the other side.